# Building up a monthly total from past 12 months

Tags: sql, database, datetime, vb6, date

```
CurrentMonth = Month(CurrentDate)
CurrentYear = Year(CurrentDate)

    SQL = "SELECT Spent, MONTH(Date) AS InvMonth, YEAR(Date) As InvYear FROM Invoices WHERE YEAR(Date) = '" & CurrentYear & "' AND MONTH(Date) = '" & CurrentMonth & "'"
    RecordSet.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    Do Until RecordSet.EOF
        MTotal(i) = MTotal(i) + RecordSet.Fields("Spent")
        RecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    RecordSet.Close
```

This is the code I currently have to build up a total spent for a given month.
I wish to expand this to retrieve the totals per month, for the past 12 months.

The way I see to do this would be to loop backwards through the CurrentMonth value, and if CurrentMonth value reaches 0 roll the value of CurrentYear back 1. Using the loop variable (i) to build up an array of 12 values: MTotal()

What do you guys think?

Comment: As written, you don't use and therefore don't need to select InvMonth and InvYear since you know the value from the input data.  You should also get the DBMS to do SUM(Spent), so you end up with one row for the given month.

Comment: (You might keep InvMonth and InvYear around for debugging purposes, but if you do that, you will need to GROUP BY them when you add the SUM).

Answer (score 1):

A group by should get you on the way.

```
SELECT TOP 12
  SUM(Spent) AS Spent
  , MONTH(Date) AS InvMonth
  , YEAR(Date) AS InvYear
FROM
  Invoices
GROUP BY
  YEAR(Date), MONTH(Date)
WHERE DATEDIFF(mm, Date, GETDATE(()) < 12
```

---

Josh's DATEDIFF is a better solution than my original TOP and ORDER BY

Comment: You probably don't want to use TOP 12. A better way would be to check for a date range. Also, avoid things like YEAR(date) = x. That prevents SQL Server from using any indexes on "date". Calculate the earliest and latest dates and do something like "date BETWEEN x AND y"

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this by "rounding" the date to the Month, and then Grouping by that month-date, and totalling the Spent amount:

```
 SELECT SUM(Spent) AS [TotalSpent],
        DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, [Date]), 0) AS [MonthDate]
 FROM   Invoices 
 WHERE      [Date] >= '20080301'
        AND [Date] <  '20090301'
 GROUP BY DATEADD(Month, DATEDIFF(Month, 0, [Date]), 0)
 ORDER BY [MonthDate]
```

The [MonthDate] can be formatted to show Month / Date appropraitely, or in separate columns.

The WHERE clause can be parameterised to provide a suitable range of records to be included

Comment: P.S. Please ask if you would like an example of the "formatting" I refer to

Comment: +1, good solution, I ended up doing this. I also think you meant "truncating", not "rounding".

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with this is that I require a monthly total, for each of the past 12 months rather then the total for the past 12 months. Otherwise I see how improving the SQL rather then using vb6 code oculd be a better option.

Comment: hmm my account seems to have been deleted. Sorry about answering with a comment guys.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with would be :

```
For i = 0 To 11
    If CurrentMonth = 0 Then
        CurrentMonth = 12
        CurrentYear = CurrentYear - 1
    End If

    SQL = "SELECT Spent, MONTH(Date) AS InvMonth, YEAR(Date) As InvYear FROM Invoices WHERE YEAR(Date) = '" & CurrentYear & "' AND MONTH(Date) = '" & CurrentMonth & "'"
    RecordSet.Open SQL, Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
    Do Until RecordSet.EOF
        MTotal(i) = MTotal(i) + RecordSet.Fields("Spent").Value
        RecordSet.MoveNext
    Loop
    RecordSet.Close

    CurrentMonth = CurrentMonth - 1
Next
```

I believe this should work as expected. However I still look forward to seeing what solutions you guys can come up, or if anyone spots an issue with ym fix.